# getting empty response in Recycleview using Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Below is my JSON

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "client":" Al Majid Science Academy",
         "city":"Bahawalpur"
      },
      {
         "client":" ENLIGHTEN CHILDREN ACADEMY ",
         "city":"Sukkur"
      },
      {
         "client":" M.U.H Model High School for Boys & Girls",
         "city":"Lahore"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al Mukhtar Public School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al-GHAZZI EVENING COLLEGE",
         "city":"Lahore"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al-Huda School System",
         "city":"Tandlianwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al-MUSLIM PUBLIC SCHOOL Garhi Sherdad",
         "city":"Peshawar"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al-Mussaver Public School Bua",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Al-Nadwa Academy Of Science Kamoke",
         "city":"Kamoke"
      },
      {
         "client":"Allied School Defense View Campus",
         "city":"Lahore"
      },
      {
         "client":"Allied School Malakwal Campus",
         "city":"Mandi Bahauddin"
      },
      {
         "client":"Best International School System",
         "city":"Arifwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"Bright Era Institute Of Sciences ",
         "city":"Gujranwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"Career School System",
         "city":"Rawalpindi"
      },
      {
         "client":"Central Science School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"CompuTech Institute (NoorKot Road Campus)",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"CompuTech Institute of Computer & Technology",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"CompuTech School System",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Crescent Public High School & College Nushki",
         "city":"Nushki"
      },
      {
         "client":"Divisional Model Public High School ",
         "city":"Ahmadpur East"
      },
      {
         "client":"Education For All Children School System",
         "city":"Daska"
      },
      {
         "client":"Faiz-e-Lasani Public Model School Hadnal",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Fusion College of Sciences",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Govt Post Graduate College",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"IIUI Schools Jauharabad",
         "city":"Jauharabad"
      },
      {
         "client":"IIUI Schools Okara Campus",
         "city":"Okara"
      },
      {
         "client":"IIUI Schools Shakargarh",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"INNOVATOR SCIENCE ACADEMY PHILOURA",
         "city":"Zafarwal"
      },
      {
         "client":"IQRA School & College Daggar",
         "city":"Buner"
      },
      {
         "client":"KBL English Academy",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"KBL Science & English Academy",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Khaliqia Educational Complex",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Kids Learning Castle",
         "city":"Muzaffarabad"
      },
      {
         "client":"Kids Learning School System",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Kids Public School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Kindergarten School System",
         "city":"Nowshera"
      },
      {
         "client":"LifeLine Model School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Little Champs School Kot Addu",
         "city":"Multan"
      },
      {
         "client":"Little Groomers School Tarnab",
         "city":"Peshawar"
      },
      {
         "client":"Mentor Nursery (School For Kids)",
         "city":"Kamoke"
      },
      {
         "client":"Minhaj ul Hussain Higher Secondary School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Muslim Grammar School",
         "city":"Karachi"
      },
      {
         "client":"NDS School",
         "city":"Lahore"
      },
      {
         "client":"New Concept Public School Chamal",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Oasis Foundation School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"PMG School Noorkot",
         "city":"Sharda"
      },
      {
         "client":"Raj Public school Mian channu",
         "city":"Mian Channu"
      },
      {
         "client":"Royal Public School (RPS)",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Sardar Grammar School ",
         "city":"Gujranwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"SHAKARGARH PUBLIC SCHOOL",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Shine Star Educational Complex Bagga",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Spirit ECE School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Super Career Group of Schools",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Swat Education Complex",
         "city":"Swat"
      },
      {
         "client":"Tabinda Public Model Higher Secondary School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Tameer -e- Nau School Abbottabad",
         "city":"Abbottabad"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Alpine Science School ",
         "city":"Haroonabad"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Eastern Grammar School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Garrison Science Secondary School",
         "city":"Multan"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Kids Paradise School",
         "city":"Gujranwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Nation School System Jhang",
         "city":"Jhang"
      },
      {
         "client":"The National School",
         "city":"Gujranwala"
      },
      {
         "client":"The New Horizon School Shakargarh",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Scholars College of Sciences Commerce ZWL",
         "city":"Zafarwal"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Vision School & Islamic Vision Girls College",
         "city":"Hyderabad"
      },
      {
         "client":"The Wisdom School",
         "city":"Shakargarh"
      },
      {
         "client":"Umm Al-Qura Islamic School",
         "city":"Okara"
      }
   ]
}
```

**ModelClass:**

```
public class Rvdata {


    private String client;
    private String city;

    public Rvdata()

    {

    }

    public Rvdata(String client, String city){
        this.client=client;
        this.city=city;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

**JsonResponse:**

```
  public class JSONResponse {
    private Rvdata[] content;

    public Rvdata[] getContent(){
        return content;
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface:**

```
   public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("EduPortal/Production/apis/services.php?call=our_clients")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Rvdata> content;

public RvAdapter(ArrayList<Rvdata> content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@Override
public RvAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_one,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv_name.setText(content.get(position).getClient());
    holder.tv_version.setText(content.get(position).getCity());
}
```

**MainClass:**

```
private void loadJSON() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://apps.eduportal-pk.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getContent()));
            adapter = new RvAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I'm new and got stuck.

Note: I also checked some other JSON in which this code works perfectly.

Comment: Are you setting a `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: yes :  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
          LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: Are you getting the data? Did you try `Logging` it out in the logcat?

Comment: Just add a back slash in your base url

Comment: i already tried by adding backslash

Comment: no thats the issue i'm not getting any data but when i tried to fetch some other json that;s working also geeting all the data in my recycleview but with this json i'm not getting anything

Comment: Well then there's obviously something in the JSON that causes it. Take away parts until it works, and then you know what causes it.

Comment: then kindly review my json n point out the issues bcx i've no idea whats wrong with it like i said i'm a beginner and i already tried my best to resolve this.

Comment: try reading about json object & json array, i guess the issue is with it, can you show the json which was working fine?

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dds861/3932d2ad026a64ccea9c86e5d20ac9b5/raw/26c68320633242159631f263a35def193bc7c3a8/json.json. -i tried this json just to test my code and it is working perfect.

Comment: Can you edit your question with mainclass full code

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the trailing slash to your baseUrl anyway otherwise Retrofit will call `https://apps.eduportal-pk.comEduPo...` and that's not a good structure for an URL. Also I've tried calling your URL in postman and I get soemthing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Developer Services</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>


{"content":[{"client":" Al Majid Science Academy","city":"Bahawalpur"},{"client":" ENLIGHTEN CHILDREN ACADEMY
","city":"Sukkur"},{"client":" M.U.H Model High School for Boys & Girls","city":"Lahore"},{"client":"Al Mukhtar Public
School","city":"Shakargarh"},{"client":"Al-GHAZZI EVENING COLLEGE","city":"Lahore"},{"client":"Al-Huda School
System","cit
...
```

Your response is not full JSON, there is some HTML code before, you should remove it.

Comment: yup i checked this now and now it's working thankx great man u saved me!